# SetWindowsHookEx c#

Tags: c#, hook, setwindowshookex

I would like to hook a specific process not a global hook but I don't know what I have to put in my SetWindowsHookEx when I call it.

I don't understand what is HookProc and the 3 third parameter.

```
public Form1()
{
    InitializeComponent();
}
public enum HookType : int
        {
            WH_JOURNALRECORD = 0,
            WH_JOURNALPLAYBACK = 1,
            WH_KEYBOARD = 2,
            WH_GETMESSAGE = 3,
            WH_CALLWNDPROC = 4,
            WH_CBT = 5,
            WH_SYSMSGFILTER = 6,
            WH_MOUSE = 7,
            WH_HARDWARE = 8,
            WH_DEBUG = 9,
            WH_SHELL = 10,
            WH_FOREGROUNDIDLE = 11,
            WH_CALLWNDPROCRET = 12,
            WH_KEYBOARD_LL = 13,
            WH_MOUSE_LL = 14
        }
[DllImport("user32.dll", SetLastError = true)]                                   
static extern uint GetWindowThreadProcessId(IntPtr hWnd, IntPtr ProcessId);

[DllImport("user32.dll", SetLastError = true)]                                  
static extern IntPtr FindWindow(string lpClassName, string lpWindowName); 
      
[DllImport("user32.dll", SetLastError = true)]
static extern IntPtr SetWindowsHookEx(HookType hookType, HookProc lpfn, IntPtr hMod, uint dwThreadId);


[DllImport("user32.dll")]
static extern int CallNextHookEx(IntPtr hhk, int nCode, IntPtr wParam, IntPtr lParam);

delegate IntPtr HookProc(int code, IntPtr wParam, IntPtr lParam);

public uint findWindowThreadId()
        {
            uint idprocess;
            idFirstGt = GetWindowThreadProcessId(FindWindow(default(string), "ProcessName"), IntPtr.Zero);
            return idProcess;
        }
public void SetHook()
        {
            hhook = SetWindowsHookEx(HookType.WH_KEYBOARD,/* HERE  , AND HERE */, findWindowThreadId());
        }
```

Thanks you !

Answer (score 0):

HookProc is the callback function (that you write) that you wish to be executed whenever the HookType occurs.

The 3rd parameter (IntPtr hMod) is only relevant if your HookProc resides in another library (aka DLL).  If the HookProc is defined in your code, then you can specify NULL for this 3rd parameter.